# Size of int, short, long, long long?

Tags: c, types, c99

According to **C99 §5.2.4.2.1-1** the following types have size which is implementation dependant. What is said is they are equal or greater in magnitude than these values:

```
short           >= 8 bits
int             >= 16 bits
long            >= 32 bits
long long       >= 64 bits
```

I have always heard that `long` is always `32-bits`, and that it is strictly equivalent to `int32_t` which looks wrong.

What is true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: The standard is by definition correct.

Comment: @klutt If you read it correcly yes, I am not sure if I am good at reading standards

Comment: The size may vary.

Comment: `SHRT_MAX` is `+32767` meaning short >= 16 bits.

Comment: Java guarantees the sizes of its basic types.  C doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my computer long is 64 bits in Linux.

Windows is the only major platform that uses the 32-bit longs in 64-bit mode, exactly because of the false assumptions being widespread in the existing code. This made it difficult to change the size of long on Windows, hence on 64-bit x86 processors longs are still 32 bits in Windows to keep all sorts of existing code and definitions compatible.

Comment: much appreciated.

Comment: C implementations for the 68000 were able to accommodate code that expected `int` to be 16 bit as well as code which expected it to be 32 bits.  Code compiled with one setting could call functions compiled with the other if functions were prototyped using either `short` or `long` instead of `int`, and library calls could invoke one of two versions of the library as needed.  The only major problems were with calls to non-prototyped or variadic functions.  I don't think it should have been unreasonable to expect that compilers for octet-based machines would continue support 32-bit `long`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard is by definition correct, and the way you interpret it is correct. The sizes of some types may vary. The standard only states the *minimum* width of these types. Usually (but not necessarily) the type `int` has the same width as the target processor.

This goes back to the old days where performance was a very important aspect. Se whenever you used an `int` the compiler could choose the fastest type that still holds *at least* 16 bits.

Of course, this approach is not very good today. It's just something we have to live with. And yes, it can break code. So if you want to write fully portable code, use the types defined in `stdint.h` like `int32_t` and such instead. Or to the very least, never use `int` if you expect the variable to hold a number not in the range `[−32,767; 32,767]`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `INT_MIN` is only guaranteed to be at least `-32767`.

Comment: Though strictly speaking, INT_MIN is guaranteed to be `<= -32768` on any platform that you can target with GCC, Clang, TCC or MSVC...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Let's define 1 million standards; where one is "ISO/IEC 9899:2011" and one is "GNU standard C" (where `INT_MIN` is <= -32768), and one is "Microsoft standard C" (where `long` is always 32-bits and it is strictly equivalent to `int32_t`).

Comment: @Brendan I'd rather see the sign-and-magnitude and one's complement be gone in ISO/EC 9899/202x

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I want the whole language scrapped and replaced with something that supports (e.g.) `range 0 to 11 myMonth;`" ;-).

Comment: and r`range 1 to 12 isoMonth`

Comment: @Brendan Well, then code Pascal or Ada. Those languages has support for that. :)

Comment: *if you want to write fully portable code, use the types defined in stdint.h like int32_t and such instead* No, `<stdint.h>` is not usually needed for full portability.  Code like `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` is perfectly fine and perfectly portable, and is much more widespread than might be imagined based on oft-heard proclamations that plain `int` is somehow nonportable and should be deprecated.

Comment: @SteveSummit The point here is: is `for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)` portable? To quote a recent meme: "Well Yes, But Actually No". When the constant is actually  something like `someVector.size()`, things become *so* tricky that I'd also hesitate to use the types with unknown sizes at all...

Comment: @SteveSummit C has an intent :-o? Seriously, I also get that point, but this certainly was designed at a time when there was not much awareness for the issues that this could cause. The portability of being able to use `int` on a 14bit microcontroller and a 32bit server is vastly different from the portability that would be desirable when trying to compile the same code on a 32bit and on a 64bit desktop PC - and the latter was certainly *hindered* by this vagueness in the spec. One could say that it achieves portability of the *language*, but not portability of *code*...

Comment: @Marco13 You're a quick reader -- I deleted my second comment ("abrogates the original intent of C") within seconds of posting it.

Comment: @Marco13 It is a complicated and contentions set of issues, I have to admit.
`<stdint.h>` is certainly a vital tool.  But (maybe I'm stubborn) I still
think that saying "plain `int` is nonportable and should never be used" is wrong.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, if you iterate from 0 to 100 it will be completely portable. But what if you later change to iterate from 0 to 40000? I'm not advocating ALWAYS using the types in stdint. Hell, I rarely use them myself. I'm just saying that it is a way to make sure that you don't do a mistake related to the varying width.

Comment: @Marco13: C was designed to be a recipe for producing useful dialects on a wide range of machines, such that somebody who is familiar with the recipe and familiar with a machine would be able to program that machine in its dialect.  The Committee tried to give programmers a "fighting chance" [their words] to write portable code, but--contrary to what some "clever" compiler writers claim--did *not* want to demean programs whose behavior wasn't 100% defined by the Standard.

Answer (score 3):

> *I have always heard that `long` is always 32-bits and it is strictly equivalent to `int32_t` which looks wrong.*

I'm curious where you heard that. It's absolutely wrong.

There are plenty of systems (mostly either 16-bit or 32-bit systems or 64-bit Windows, I think) where `long` is 32 bits, but there are also plenty of systems where `long` is 64 bits.

(And even if `long` is 32 bits, it may not be the same type as `int32_t`. For example, if `int` and `long` are both 32 bits, they're still distinct types, and `int32_t` is probably defined as one or the other.)

```
$ cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("long is %zu bits\n", sizeof (long) * CHAR_BIT);
}
$ gcc -m32 c.c -o c && ./c
long is 32 bits
$ gcc -m64 c.c -o c && ./c
long is 64 bits
$
```

The requirements for the sizes of the integer types are *almost* as you stated in your question (you had the wrong size for `short`). The standard actually states its requirements in terms of ranges, not sizes, but that along with the requirement for a binary representation implies minimal sizes in bits. The requirements are:

- `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char` : 8 bits
- `short`, `unsigned short`: 16 bits
- `int`, `unsigned int`: 16 bits
- `long`, `unsigned long`: 32 bits
- `long long`, `unsigned long long`: 64 bits

Each signed type has a range that includes the range of the previous type in the list. There are no upper bounds.

It's common for `int` and `long` to be 32 and 64 bits, respectively, particularly on non-Windows 64-bit systems. (POSIX requires `int` to be at least 32 bits.) `long long` is exactly 64 bits on every system I've seen, though it can be wider.

Comment: In the days before the Standard, it was generally recognized that `char` is the smallest addressable unit of at least 8 bits, `short` is the smallest practical type that's at least 16 bits, `int` is the most practical type that's at least 16 bits, and `long` is the most practical type that's at least 32 bits.  On anything resembling typical microcomputers, that implied sizes of exactly 8, 16, 16 or 32, and 32 bits, respectively, and I don't think the authors of the Standard intended that typical microcomputers shouldn't be expected to use those sizes.

Comment: @supercat: I'm typing this on a system with 64-bit `long`. Do you seriously think the authors of the Standard would have a problem with that? Or do you have some odd meaning in mind for "typical microcomputers"? (Note that neither the standard nor the question I answered said anything about microcomputers.)

Comment: I think at least some of the authors of the Standard would be disappointed at designs that couldn't accommodate code expecting a 32-bit `long`.  Compilers for the 68000 could routinely be configured to use either 16 or 32-bit `int`, and supporting a similar choice between 32-bit and 64-bit `long` should have been even easier because of the lack of integer-promotion issues when calling variadic functions.  Even on a 64-bit machine, using arrays of 32-bit values will often be faster than using 64-bit values in cases where 32-bit range would be adequate.

Comment: On the classic Macintosh, code written with one `int` setting could interoperate with code using the other provided that all functions were properly prototyped, none used variadic functions or `va_list`, and none tried to pass the addresses of any standard library functions that used type `int`.  Unlike the 68000, x64 can pass 64-bit arguments for the same cost as 32-bit ones, so what difficulty should there be with having a special compiler types for "32-bit signed passed as 64 bits with sign-extended padding" and "32-bit unsigned passed as 64 bits with zero padding"...

Comment: ...and having the headers for most library functions use those instead of `long` when set for 32-bit `long` mode, and having the headers for functions that accept a `long*` substitute a reserved-name version which expects a `int32_t*` instead?

Comment: When the Standard was written, and for quite awhile afterward, an implementation's ability to reliably process a wide variety of non-portable programs was generally recognized as more important than the performance with which it could process Strictly Conforming programs.  Given that the authors of the Standard have expressly denied any intention to demean or deprecate the use of constructs whose behavior isn't mandated by the Standard, on what basis should programmers have foreseen the eagerness of some compiler writers to do so?

Comment: @supercat: Rather than adding all this noise to my answer, why don't you post one of your own? It is beyond dispute that the standard *permits* `long` to be 64 bits.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23769101)

Comment: @Rob: I disagree, but I'll add some more information. In any case, it seems odd that my answer (which currently has 3 upvotes and no downvotes) showed up in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. Apparently somebody flagged it. I won't speculate on who might have done so.

Comment: Yes, someone else flagged it and, reading this in context of the question along with your edit, I'm going to see if I can retract that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Standard doesn't specify *sizes* for types like `int`, `short`, `long`, etc., but rather a *minimum range of values* that those types must be able to represent.

For example, an `int` must be able to represent *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`<sup>1</sup>, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide.  It may be wider for two reasons:

- The platform offers more *value bits* to store a wider range (e.g., x86 uses 32 bits to store integer values and 64 bits for long integers);
- The platform uses *padding bits* that store something other than part of the value.

As an example of the latter, supposed you have a 9-bit platform with 18-bit words.  In the case of the 18-bit word, two of the bits are padding bits and are *not* used to store part of the value - the type can still only store `[-32767..32767]`, even though it's wider than 16 bits.

The `<stdint.h>` header does define integer types with specific, fixed sizes (16-bit, 32-bit), but they may not be available everywhere.

---

1. C does not mandate 2's complement representation for signed integers, which is why the range doesn't go from `[-32768..32767]`.